# Spotlight Autocomplete Suggesting the Wrong App

Tags: shortcut, spotlight, auto-complete

I recently downloaded GoodNotes and now whenever I try to open Notes via Spotlight, I accidentally open GoodNotes because GoodNotes is strangely the first result when I type "notes"! (A little petty, but can be quite frustrating when I'm trying to work quickly and I repeatedly pull up GoodNotes by accident.)

**Is there anyway that I could make GoodNotes always appear as the second result, or simply not appear when I search "notes" and only appear when I search "goodnotes"?**

I would rather not remove the app entirely from Spotlight's results ([as in this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/191028/removing-a-specific-app-from-spotlight)). Rather, I just don't want it to appear when I type "notes" -- I just want the native Notes app to appear when I type that.

[image]

Comment: It generally learns by your behaviour, so if you keep launching the wrong one, it pats itself on the head for being a good boy & does it again next time. Train it like a small puppy, only reward correct behaviour ;))

Comment: I do notice that it remembers the last application I opened (most of the time). Sometimes it still suggests GoodNotes even when I've only been using Notes. (I use Notes 95% of the time and it still brings GoodNotes to top result very frequently.)... So in short, I don't think that's a real solution to this issue.